# Setting hierarchical rules in firebase by comparing array to an array in firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am making realtime chat of my app using firebase. The login is userId based. so the auth.uid is this userId. A user is owner of many profiles(say of his family members), and a profile can belong to multiple users(say a child profile can belong to his father and mother). Now a chat is always on behalf of a profile(i.e. a father and wife can send chatMessage on behalf of their son). I want to set security rules for this chat.
The issues which I am facing are

Only the users whose profile has created a chat-message can edit that message. I am unable to set this security as I would have to compare an array to an array for which I have to write a function in security rules which firebase does not allow.

```
Users:{
    userIdOfVed:{
        profiles:{
            userProfileIdOfVedSon:{
                profileId:userProfileIdOfVedSon,
                relation:son
            },
            __:{...},
            __:{...},
            ...
        }
    },
    __:{...},
    __:{...},
    ...
}


Profiles:{
    userProfileIdOfVedSon:{
        chats:{
            chatRoom1Id:{
                caseId:case32Id,
                chatRoomId:chatRoom1Id
            },
            chatRoom3Id:{
                caseId:case42Id,
                chatRoomId:chatRoom3Id
            }
        }
        //...Other user data(like email, phone no.) which might be required
    },
    __:{...},
    __:{...},
    ...
}

ChatMetadata:{
    chatRoom1Id:{
        createdOn:ISODate("2017-04-13T11:25:35.668Z"),
        members:{
            userProfileIdOfVedSon:{
                userProfileId:userProfileIdOfVedSon
            },
            __:{...},
            __:{...},
            ...
        },
        users:{},//I want to avoid putting this field as least as possible, but if its very critical for setting security, then there is no avoiding it.
        caseId:case32Id,
        lastMessage:"hello world"
        //...Other chat meta data(like last message,etc) which might be required
    },
    __:{...},
    __:{...},
    ...
}

Chats:{
    chatRoom1Id:{
        message1Id:{ //these are randomly generated messageIds by firebase
            userId:userIdOfVed,
            userProfileId:1,
            message:"hello world",
            timestamp:1459361875337 //can be replaced by a standard date time format
        },
        message2Id:{...},
        message3Id:{...}
    },
    chatRoom2Id:{
        message34Id:{...},
        message69Id:{...}
    }
}


//Rules for reading the realtime database
//The list of profiles can be put in the payload of the auth token (auth.profiles) which is not implemented yet
Users:{
    $userId:{ //A user can only read/write/modify his $userId key-value object
        "./read": "$userId == auth.uid"
    }
}
Profiles:{
    $profileId:{ //Can be read/write/modified by  Users who have access to this profiles. 
        ".read": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('profiles').child($profileId).exists()"
    }
}
ChatMetaData:{
    $chatRoomId:{ //Only the profiles who are present in its "members" keys can read it and a profile can only modify his $profileId entry in "members".
        ".read": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()"
    }
}
Chats:{
    $chatRoomId:{ //Only the profiles who are present in "ChatMetadata.$chatRoodId.members" keys can read it and push new values in it.(optional: modification to a child can be done only if that profile belongs to "ChatMetadata.$chatRoodId.members" & his profileId==the child.profileId)
        ".read":"I AM UNABLE TO FIGURE OUT THIS RULE, AS FIREBASE DOES NOT ALLOW FUNCTIONS INSIDE THIS."
    }
}
```

TL;DR: Can I compare array to an array in firebase security rules to set hierarchical rules

Comment: Firebase will not store arrays in its database: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Could we solve this without using arrays?